# Enable Google Assistant Actions for Android Wear?

Tags: actions-on-google

How can a custom action be enabled for Android Wear? I have developed a custom Action that works fine on Google Home and the Assistant app on phone. On a watch though, it says "Not Supported". I looked at surface settings on the Actions Console but don't see any Wear specific settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment there is no support for Android Wear. However, if you are using your webhook you can call the same 'server side' from your wear app and give the user you service on it as well. But it won't be part of the 'assistant'.